# Resize height of layout only from one direction: Animation Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I am trying to resize my layout with an animation in android. The problem is that the layout starts shrinking from both directions. I just want it to reduce from the bottom. I tried setting the pivot but it doesn't work.

```
    layout.setPivotY(0f);
    layout.setPivotX(0f);
    ValueAnimator va = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mFragmentheight, mFragmentheight/2);
    va.setDuration(400);
    va.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {

        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            Integer value = (Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue();
            layout.getLayoutParams().height = value.intValue();
            layout.requestLayout();
        }
    });
    va.start();


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <RelativeLayout
      android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@color/green"
      android:orientation="vertical">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_cancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/cancel"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/confirm"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="83dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/confirm"
        android:text="Are you sure you want to exit"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
     />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/img"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/exitBtn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingRight="5dp"
          android:text="@string/exit"
          android:textAllCaps="true"
          android:textSize="16.0sp"
        />

      <Button
          android:id="@+id/closeBtn"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingLeft="5dp"
          android:text="@string/cancel"
          android:textAllCaps="true"
          android:textSize="14.0sp"
          />
    </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>

</merge>
```

Comment: Can you post your layout file?

Comment: @MarcinJedynak Please check the layout.

Comment: Whatever View your Fragment is in seems to have gravity set to center.  You need to pin it the top of the View somewhere first. Or you can translate it up in the same amount of pixels your shrinking it.

Comment: @DeeV Thank you so much for your response. You're right.I had set the gravity of the view as center. It works perfectly now :) Please add your solution as an answer so that I can accept it.